# twitteR packaging throwing error when trying to search for tweets by geocode

Tags: r, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am trying to collect tweets based on a geolocation using the searchTwitter function.

`geocode = ="40.6687,74.1143,1mi" text = "" count = 200 bList<- searchTwitter(text, n=count, geocode=geocode)`

When I run this code, I get an error stating "200 tweets were requested but the API can only return 0". I am not looking for tweets more than 7 days old and have no whitespace in my geocode, which were solutions to previously asked questions about this function.
Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

I have tried looking at similar problems online but I cannot figure out why there is an error.